# SMB-Get Nodejs getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, express, smb

I'm currently trying to connect to a SMB server from a Debian machine. i've downloaded ths SMB2-Client from https://github.com/bchelli/node-smb2 , ive done the example

```
var SMB2 = require('smb2');

// create an SMB2 instance
var smb2Client = new SMB2({
  share:'\\\\xxx/appfolder/\\'
, domain:'xxx'
, username:'teste'
, password:'teste'
});


smb2Client.exists('/Base_dados.mdb', function (err, exists) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(exists ? "it's there" : "it's not there!");
});
```

i'm getting the current error

```
  /home/sergio/Desktop/node-access/index.js:14
    if (err) throw err;
                   ^
```

If anyone has any idea on how to solve this, would be greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: the rest of the options above the share, how should i complete? or are optional? thanks

Answer (score 0):

the problem was based on the path

```
'\\\\xxx\\app_folder'
```

fixed the problem.